# Empty a folder to put another file inside

Tags: php

I would like to empty a folder (with chmod 777) before uploading a file :

```
$files = glob($targetdir); // get all file names
        foreach($files as $file)
        { // iterate files
          if(is_file($file))
            unlink($file); // delete file
        }
```

My folder has a right path builded with this code :

```
$targetdir = 'cartes_identites/'.$mds['nom'].' '.$mds['prenom'].'_verso';
```

My folder still full of files, I have to keep only one, uploaded with this code :

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['id_card_recto']['tmp_name'], $targetfile))
        {
          echo "file uploaded succeeded";
        }
```

Comment: I think you need a `/.*` or something in there.  Basically a wildcard.  I dont use `glob` much as I prefer using the SPL classes.

Answer (score 0):

apply file path *.*

```
 $targetdir = 'cartes_identites/'.$mds['nom'].' '.$mds['prenom'].'_verso/*.*';
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's about emptying entire folder, instead loop use simple Linux command:

```
if(is_dir($targetdir)){
    $output = shell_exec("rm -rf ".escapeshellarg($targetdir)."/*");
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
}
```

**Make sure your target directory is absolutely correct.**

Comment: `escapeshellarg()` - might be a nice addition, never know what `$targetdir` is, maybe it's a command to add a user etc.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php > `Escape a string to be used as a shell argument`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Agree, editing answer.

Comment: Thank you, it does not work.  I'm sure about the path of the directory.  My console shows this "<pre></pre>

Comment: Can you just run "rm -rf dir" command in your console with your directory path, and let us know the result.